# AWS Lambda s3 Object Changes listener for WebSockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket, aws-lambda

I am using a WebSockets API to connect my front end which deals with displaying information on files being updated in the backend, stored in an S3 Bucket.
The lambda handling the main action for this api is asynchronous, and every time that a file in my S3 changes, I want the lambda to send a message to the frontend. I have tried:

```
try {
   var list = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
await send(JSON.stringify(list));
```

But this only sends a message when the listObjects is called, not when there is a change in the bucket.

Can I do this the same way you can get an s3 change to trigger a Lambda function?

TIA